# [uncaught application error]: TypeError - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')

Tags: angular

I get this error message when I try to test the /api/auth/signup end point with Postman and following POST request:

[This is the error I get when I try to use the sign Up method.][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FGLL.png

[This is the second error I get when I try to use the sign In method.][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzaeS.png

Comment: Hi, please edit your question by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You must not send screenshots of code or errors, copy and paste them in your question so people can use them easily.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the response be in curly braces?

```js
{ 
"email" : "stanleydavis393@gmail.com",
"password": "janes@gmail.com"
}
```

Comment: I tried that it is still throwing up the same error.